# RestSharp deserialize JSON content(represent an object contains an byte array) error

Tags: json, arrays, deserialization, restsharp

The Client side receives a formal JSON content `"{\"Id\":[1,2,3],\"Size\":56}"`, but get an error in deserialization the byte array.

1 Error occurs in the statement below

```
IRestResponse<key> response = client.Execute<key>(request);
```

2 Error message is "No parameterless constructor defined for this object."

3 The object class in client size is the same as it's in server side:

```
public class key
{
    public byte[] id { get; set; }
    public int Size { set; get; }
}
```

4 I've tried passing object that contains string and integer by JSON format and that's all fine but byte array.

Answer (score 54):

JsonDeserializer from RestSharp can not deserialize array. Instead of `byte[]` use `List<byte>`. For more information see https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/Deserialization

Comment: This happened to me as well, I finally figured out I had left a pesky string array laying around in one of my classes.  Changing it to a List<string> fixed the problem immediately and all tests started passing.

Answer (score 26):

I have run into this issue, too.  My solution was to use RestSharp to perform a raw execute and use Json.NET to deserialize the result:

```
var response = client.Execute(request);
var keyResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<key>(response.Content);
```

keyResponse should now be an instance of your key class deserialized from the JSON content.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Chris Hogan's reply, I'd like to point out that I got this error when RestSharp incorrectly used the default serializer instead of the custom JSON.NET serializer I had assigned.

The reason for this was that I added a handler with content type `application/json` whereas the API I was getting the response from returned the content as `text/json`.

So by changing the `AddHandler` call to `AddHandler("text/json", jsonDeserializer)`, I resolved the issue.