# Can RestSharp handle byte arrays?

Tags: json, serialization, restsharp

I'm using RestSharp. I was using XML as the transport encoding for my data, but then I [had problems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11799750/98422) with that, so I switched to using JSON. Now I'm having problems with that too!

All was well until I tried to pass an object containing a byte array (*). Now I get a de-serialization error complaining about "object has no parameterless constructor". (The JSON returned by the server looks Kosher - it's just not being correctly de-serialized by RestSharp).

I see I'm [not the only one having problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10890790/restsharp-deserialize-json-contentrepresent-an-object-contains-an-byte-array-e). Is there no solution other than the baby-out-with-the-bathwater approach suggested in that post?

(*) I had tested it with a small hand-coded byte array early on in my development, just to check that it worked. It *did* work then, but doesn't work now. I don't know if that's due to the size of the array, the "characters" in the array, or what. Dammit, this has been such a time-sink!

Comment: Just curious, what happens if you declare List<byte> instead of byte[] ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone else struggling with this, I ended up simply swapping out the JSON formatter in favour of JSON.NET. That works.